# How to find the central angle if the area of minor segment is known

Tags: python, geometry

The area of the minor/major segment is known. I need to find the value of central angle or the length of the chord.

I was able to reach an equation which is something like `theta - sin(theta) = constant` which seems unsolvable right now.

Is there anything that can be calculated using this info, like the length of the  chord, or the height of the triangle.

Also, from Python point of view, is there any library that can solve the equation `theta - sin(theta) = constant`

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What `minor/major segments` are you talking about? Please make the question more clear, provide a picture if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Let the minor segment's area be `A`, and the major `B`. Unless I'm wrong you got [image].

There is no way to solve this analytically (it's transcendental), but you can use a method such as Newton-Raphson. Use the following iteration:

[image]

Since `0 ≤  ≤` , there can only be one solution...

[image]

... so start from say /4 or something.

Answer (score 0):

This seems better off being asked at https://math.stackexchange.com/. In any case, given the areas of the two segments, you can add them up and derive the radius of the circle. Try asking over there if there is some way to find the angle between those two new line segments having length = r.